# Reset Bootstrap Dropdown Button Value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap Dropdown component in place of a normal select menu. When the user selects an option in the dropdown it's then displayed on the Dropdown button. This works fine but I need to allow the user to reset the button back to default with an onclick function.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills left">
            <li class="dropdown active span8">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="inp_impact" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="icon icon-envelope icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Select<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul ID="divNewNotifications" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a>One</a></li> 
                          <li><a>Two</a></li>       
                            <li><a>Three</a></li>                         
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <button class="resetdropdown">Clear</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#divNewNotifications li').on('click', function() {
$('.dropdown-toggle').html($(this).find('a').html());
});


$('.resetdropdown').on('click', function() {
$('.dropdown-toggle').html(" ");
});
```

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enzDx/326/) demonstrates the issue.

As you can see when the 'Clear' button is clicked it removes everything from the Bootstrap Dropdown button, but this is wrong as I need to just reset back to the default value as if the page had been refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the Clear button itself in order to save the default value of your dropdown as an atttribute of your button.

At dom ready you may save such a value and handle the click event in one piece of code:

```
$('.resetdropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    //
    // if the attribute doesn't exist add it...
    //
    if ($(this).attr('defValue') == undefined) {
        $(this).attr('defValue', ' ' + $('.dropdown-toggle')
              .contents().get(2).textContent + ' ');
    } else {
        //
        // ...else do the click event stuff
        //
        $('.dropdown-toggle').contents().get(2).textContent = 
                 ' ' + $(this).attr('defValue') + ' ';
    }
}).trigger('click');  // trigger the click immediately after event handler declaration.
```

The snippet ([updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enzDx/327/)):

```js
$('#divNewNotifications li').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').contents().filter(function(idx, ele) {
        return ele.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && ele.textContent.trim().length != 0
    }).get(0).textContent = ' ' + this.textContent.trim() + ' ';
});


$('.resetdropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('defValue') == undefined) {
        $(this).attr('defValue', ' ' + $('.dropdown-toggle').contents().get(2).textContent + ' ');
    } else {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').contents().get(2).textContent = ' ' + $(this).attr('defValue') + ' ';
    }
}).trigger('click');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-pills left">
    <li class="dropdown active span8">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="inp_impact" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="icon icon-envelope icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Select<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul ID="divNewNotifications" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a>One</a></li>
            <li><a>Two</a></li>
            <li><a>Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<button class="resetdropdown">
    Clear
</button>
```

Comment: hi this is really helpful, can you help me how can I reset dropdown in this type of format?
http://jsfiddle.net/enzDx/340/

Comment: Thank you very much @gaetanoM

Comment: @monisogani The updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/enzDx/343/) Let me know if it works.

Comment: @gaetanoM: sorry I have change request, how can I achieve this when having multiple dropdowns on a single page and a single clear button to reset all dropdowns?
here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/enzDx/344/

Answer (score 0):

You should store your default value in variable and inject it in the reset function.